# How to retain/share complex GL view between different Android activity instances

Tags: android, optimization, navigation, glsurfaceview

I have a regular Android app with a few simple activities and standard navigation. Now I'm adding the complex activity (`MapActivity`) with `GLSurfaceView` (`MapView`). `MapView` takes a few seconds to initialize (GL context, shaders, textures, buffers, etc.) and uses pretty much of memory. 
I still want to leave the default navigation (ability to start any activity from the current, including new `MapActivity`, and be able to return on back press). The app is designed in a way that user might often switch back and forth between the map and other activities.
All I want is to retain the `MapView` (at least, GL context), so it is not destroyed every time I press the back button and is not recreated when I start a new instance of `MapActivity` which uses it.

How to achieve this?

I tried to make `MapActivity` singletask/singleinstance. This way it destroys view on back press. Also it becomes to sit in separate task, so I do worry if I can seamlessly navigate back to previous `MapActivity` states in history (though haven't checked this yet).

I also tried to share the whole `MapView` instance between different instances of `MapActivity` but this doesn't seem to work either.

`MapActivity` is not the app's entry point. 
I use OpenGL ES 2.0 context.

Comment: You will likely need to switch from GLSurfaceView to plain SurfaceView, as that will give you greater control over the GLES context lifetime.  Retaining the GLES context when the user switches to a different app isn't great for the user, as it means your app is holding on to resources rather than sharing them with other apps, so you need to be careful with this.

Comment: Well, but I just want to keep it while user is navigating within my app. It is ok for me to free everything if he goes outside.